# Apple privacy questions if only using SKAdNetwork and not IDFA for Admob

Tags: ios, admob, tracking, idfa

I researched quite a while and cannot find a definite answer to my question: How to answer Apples privacy questions in regards to Admob while using only SKAdNetwork and not intending to track users with the IDFA.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/data-disclosure

If anyone has experience in it I am very thankful for help!

Andreas